# Prefab follow player object?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

In short, I have a 2d game where a ninja will spawn in and throw ninja stars at my player. I made my ninja stars a child of my ninja enemy and drag my ninja in to the project folder to make it a prefab. in order for my ninja stars to follow my player I had to make him a prefab as well. my player has a go to mouse script attach to it, my player moves by mouse touch. I notice that whenever I move my player the ninja stars doesn't directly follow my player prefab, but goes to the last place I placed my player prefab in the scene view. I found out the problem of my problem, it was because I place my player prefab in the script prefab field for my ninja stars, when I tried to put my player object in the script prefab field for my ninja stars it wouldn't work. Is there a way in which I can make my ninja stars follow my player instead of following my player prefab? Thank you. Ninja star script:

```
#pragma strict

var Player : Transform;
var MoveSpeed = 4;
var MaxDist = 10;
var MinDist = 5;


 function Start () 
{
  GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = Random.Range(-200, 200);
  Destroy(gameObject, 2.4);
}

 function Update () 
{

    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist){

       transform.position += (Player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

   }
 }
```

And an image to follow up with what I am saying. (george_0 is my player and the Follow ME script in my ninja stars following script.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wc5p.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player doesn't need to be a prefab for this. It's not bad to make it one, but thats for other reasons (you can't have the prefab be assigned to that Player variable to make the following work is what I mean by this). You can get it in the `Start` function of your ninja star e.g. by doing a `Player = GameObject.Find("george_0");`.

Also you have `var Player : Transform`, but then use `Player.transform.position` which would basically be `transform.transform.position`. Make Player a GameObject or use just `Player.position`. Depending on this you may have to change the `Find()` to `Player = GameObject.Find("george_0").transform;`.

For the actual movement I'd say do something like this (assuming Player is a Transform in this case):

```
function Update()
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position, Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed);
    }
}
```